# CSharp virtual method and parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, virtual, overriding

```
public abstract class State
{
public virtual Enter(/* THIS NEED A PARAMETER */)
{
// an empty method
}
}

public class PlayerState : State
{
public override Enter(Player pl)
{
// method implementation
}
}

public class GoalkeeperState : State
{
public override Enter(Goalkeeper gk)
{
// method implementation
}
}

//EXAMPLE OF USE
public State globalState;
globalState.Enter(owner);
// OWNER CAN BE PLAYER OR GOALKEEPER
```

I understand that the virtual and overriden methods need to have the same "print". So there is a design flaw here. So is something like this possible. How can I do this ?
How would you do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Generics here:

```
public abstract class State<T>
{
    public virtual Enter(T item)
    {
        // an empty method
    }
}

public class PlayerState : State<Player>
{
    public override Enter(Player pl)
    {
        // method implementation
    }
}

public class GoalkeeperState : State<Goalkeeper>
{
    public override Enter(Goalkeeper gk)
    {
        // method implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: and make State an interface maybe

Comment: Or make `Enter` abstract, too. I think we don't know enough about the code, so I concentrated on answering the direct question and avoided giving hints that may be wrong in his scenario.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth many classes that do not need these kinds of methods inherit from the class

Comment: This solves the issue in one way, but we need the OP to clarify if the same instance of the `globalState` object can take a `Player` or `Goalkeeper` (the object is called `globalState`, does it allow more than one instance?) i.e. should it be a base class instead?

Comment: @Orvel: If your first comment is a question, you should formulate it as one. If it is not a question, I have no idea what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: @Charleh the State classes are singletons

Comment: @Orvel: A method can't be a singleton, only classes can.

Comment: Singletons? A plural of a singleton also doesn't make sense

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Its not a question, I was just stating that making Enter method abstract would force override, and I have more classes that inherit from the State class.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth "A method can't be a singleton, only classes can."
An accidental mistake, fixed now

Comment: @charleh There are more of classes that inherit from the State class(PlayerStates, GoalkeeperState etc.), that is what I meant.

Comment: @Orvel: Ah, ok. As you might have noticed, I didn't even know what the comment was aimed at. Now it's clear. In that case, making it abstract isn't a good idea. However, it is a good idea to think about refactoring. I think your `State` class contains too much if you have derived classes that only need part of its functionality.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It is not a big class, it only consists of 4 methods. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

you could define

```
public override Enter(State pl)
```

or, but i'm not sure i understood what you want to do correctly, something like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public virtual Enter() {}
}

public class GoalKeeper : Player
{
    public override Enter() {}
}


public class State
{
    public List<Player> players {get; private set;}

    public State() { players = new List<Player(); }
}
```